# Split Excel Column and Copy Data into New Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 20k records. It contains columns A - J. Column D has multiple entries separated by £. I would like to split Column D data into multiple rows along with the data in columns A-C and E-J.

Input:

```
Blue    Long    Car £ Motorcycle £ Skateboard   Hard    Hazel  
Green   Short   House £ Motel                   Soft    Pink  
Red     Hot     Room £ Yard £ Fort £ Castle     Medium  Yellow
```

Output:

```
Blue    Long    Car         Hard    Hazel  
Blue    Long    Motorcycle  Hard    Hazel  
Blue    Long    Sketeboard  Hard    Hazel  
Green   Short   House       Soft    Pink  
Green   Short   Motel       Soft    Pink  
Red     Hot     Room        Medium  Yellow  
Red     Hot     Yard        Medium  Yellow  
Red     Hot     Fort        Medium  Yellow  
Red     Hot     Casle       Medium  Yellow
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Jack

Comment: I am not clear on your data layout. So is "Blue" in column B in your input data - if "Car £ Motorcycle £ Skateboard" is in column D? And then "Hard" and "Hazel" are in E and F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that will split the data as specified.  Variables are used in the code to set the range so can be changed if required

```
Sub SplitData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim dataSplit() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long
    Dim col As Long, cols As Long
    Dim rws() As String
    Dim addr As String
    Dim rw As Long

    cols = 10 ' Column J
    col = 4 'column D

    'Assuming the active shsets contains the data
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Assuming data starts in A1 and column A is contiguous
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, cols), ws.[A1].End(xlDown))

    ' Get data into an array
    data = rng
    j = 1

    ' Count number of £ in data
    addr = rng.Columns(col).Address
    rw = Evaluate("=SUM(LEN(" & addr & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & addr & ",""£"","""")))")

    ' Size destination array
    ReDim dataSplit(1 To UBound(data, 1) + rw, 1 To cols)

    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        ' if contains £ then split it
        If InStr(data(i, col), "£") > 0 Then
            ' copy several rows into destination array
            rws = Split(data(i, col), "£")
            For n = 0 To UBound(rws)
                For k = 1 To cols
                    dataSplit(j + n, k) = data(i, k)
                Next
                dataSplit(j + n, col) = Trim(rws(n))
            Next
            j = j + UBound(rws) + 1
        Else
            ' copy one row into destination array
            For k = 1 To cols
                dataSplit(j, k) = data(i, k)
            Next
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' put resut back into sheet
    rng.Resize(UBound(dataSplit, 1), cols) = dataSplit

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this method over and over again and is not really working for me.

Comment: Then there is somthing I ahvn't understood correctly about your problem, probably about the layout of your data. Can you post some more info, perhaps a before and after scrren shot showing exactly what you have and what you want to get

Comment: Can I email you a copy of the sample spreadsheet? Then you'll be able see exactly what the issue is. Cheers.

Comment: Actually it works the way it was intended. My problem was that I had no data in rows 1 & 3, I I eliminated the blank rows and it works like a charm! Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: @Jack glad to have helped.  If you are satisfied with an answer, you should accept it, this is how others know the question is complete.  See [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/159408)

Answer (score 2):

If your initial data was in columns A:E with you " £ " column in C then this code will split it and dump to cell H1

You can vary the working range by

1. changing your initial data layout in this line `Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp)).Value2` (currently sets A:E)
2. choose which of the columns to split from range in (1) with this line `arrVar = Split(X(lngRow, 3), " £ ")` (currently splits the third column)
3. as per (2) update the column to split in this code line `Y(3, lngCnt) = arrVar(lngCol)` (currently splits the third column)

[image: sample]

```
Option Base 1
Sub SplitEm()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim lngRecord As Long
    Dim X
    Dim Y()
    Dim arrVar() As String

    X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp)).Value2
    'Use a tranposed array to store the results so that the 2nd dimension can be resized very 1000 records
    ReDim Y(5, 1000)

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        'Split middle column by " £ "
        arrVar = Split(X(lngRow, 3), " £ ")
        For lngCol = LBound(arrVar) To UBound(arrVar)
            lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
            'redim storage array if needed
            If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(5, UBound(Y, 2) + 1000)
            'dump 5 new records
               For lngRecord = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
                    Y(lngRecord, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, lngRecord)
            Next
            'update record 3 with the split text
            Y(3, lngCnt) = arrVar(lngCol)
        Next lngCol
    Next lngRow
    [h1].Resize(UBound(Y, 2), UBound(Y, 1)).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me :-(. I'm only getting the headers starting on H1.

Comment: @JackSparrow we need more info on your data layout .... can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I can send you a sample copy of the spreadsheet if you prefer. Please let me know. jack@sbnai.com