# Sorting columns into rows (with a random length) by key columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Happy Pride Day-After!

A bit of a tricky one that i've been trying to work through for a while.

I'm trying to sort three columns into random length rows between 3 & 11 cells, where Column A & B are essentially keys.

A simple example of what i'm trying to achieve is:

[image]

Turned into:

[image]

Some key things to note:

- The maximum number of cells in a row should be 11.
- The amount of cells in a row must be of random lengths, between 3 - 11 never exceeding 11 (the randomisation isn't essential).
- The first (A) and second (B) columns are keys.

Below is some code i've been trying to modify to attempt this, as well as a few websites and Stackoverflow's of people trying to achieve a similar thing for reference.

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 2
        Dim columnToConcatenate As Integer: columnToConcatenate = 1

        lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate)
            .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

References:

- [Move Cells into New Row Once Limit is Reached](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/506855-move-cells-into-new-row-once-limit-reached.html)
- [Excel tab to new line after certain amount of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027171/excel-tab-to-new-line-after-certain-amount-of-columns)
- [Split Excel Column and Copy Data into New Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859110/split-excel-column-and-copy-data-into-new-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably approach this as a 2 step process instead of trying to rearrange the worksheet in place.  Gather all of the data into an appropriate structure first, then clear the worksheet and write the results back to it.

For the data collection, a Dictionary of Collections is a good way to go because it will allow you to gather data based on your two column keys.  Since you don't know how many values you'll need to store, a Collection is a good container (although an array of String would work as well). The data collection function would look something like this:

```
Private Function GatherData(sheet As Worksheet) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim results As New Scripting.Dictionary
    With sheet
        Dim key As String
        Dim currentRow As Long
        For currentRow = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            key = .Cells(currentRow, 1) & "|" & .Cells(currentRow, 2)
            If Not results.Exists(key) Then results.Add key, New Collection
            results(key).Add .Cells(currentRow, 3).Value
        Next currentRow
    End With
    Set GatherData = results
End Function
```

You'll need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  Also note that this doesn't require the input to be sorted.

Once you have the data, writing it out is fairly easy.  Just iterate through the keys and write the collection based on whatever parameters you need:

```
Private Sub WriteResults(sheet As Worksheet, data As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentCol As Long
    Dim index As Long
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim id() As String
    Dim values As Collection

    currentRow = 2
    For Each key In data.Keys
        id = Split(key, "|")
        Set values = data(key)
        currentCol = 3
        With sheet
            .Cells(currentRow, 1) = id(0)
            .Cells(currentRow, 2) = id(1)
            For index = 1 To values.Count
                .Cells(currentRow, currentCol) = values(index)
                currentCol = currentCol + 1
                If currentCol > 11 And index < values.Count Then
                    currentRow = currentRow + 1
                    currentCol = 3
                    .Cells(currentRow, 1) = id(0)
                    .Cells(currentRow, 2) = id(1)
                End If
            Next index
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        End With
    Next key
End Sub
```

Note that this doesn't randomize the collection of names or the number in each row if there are more than 9, but it would be fairly easy to extract the inner loop into another Sub to do that.

Put it all together like this:

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Dim data As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set target = ActiveSheet
    Set data = GatherData(target)
    target.UsedRange.ClearContents
    WriteResults target, data
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for this! Any idea why I would be getting a `ByRef Argument Type Mismatch` on `(target)`?

Comment: @Gile - Ran fine for me.  Which line?

Comment: `Set data = GatherData(target)`

Comment: @Giles - Can't replicate here.  Is there any other code in the module?

Comment: Well I tried splitting the Sub & Private Sub's into different modules but that chucked me a **Sub or Function Not Defined** error on the line `Set data = GatherData(target)` specifically `GatherData` so I put all of your above code into one module so the only other code within the module is the two Private Sub's.

Comment: @Giles - Is `target` declared anywhere else, maybe as a global?  Try changing the variable `target` to some other identifier, put all of the above code in its own module with nothing else, and see if that clears it up. You can also safely declare as `Dim target As Object`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81742/discussion-between-comintern-and-giles).

Comment: Set the Dim, sorted and seems to be working as it should. Thank you so much for your help! On the move but will update later once I've been through it all.